# Unity 2d on multi monitor, Close, Min, Max-Buttons not available on 2nd screen

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, menu, unity-2d

In Unity 2D and a multi monitor setup (Ubuntu 11.10), the Buttons for Closing, Minimizing and Maximizing windows are not available on the second screen, if the windows are maximized.

There is also no panel showing on the second screen. So there is no menu available for applications on the second screen.

In 11.04, when an window was in Fullscreen on screen 2 the Close, Min, Max Buttons where available on the top left corner of screen one. If I needed the menu from an application maximized on scrren two, I minimized or better said Centered it, pushed it to the first screen used the menu and returned it on screen two.

Now this seems undoable.

Comment: I have my monitors aligned, but in my case left/right from each other, they are bottom/top from each other, which means the menus won't show ever aparently

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem of not having a close button or minimize/maximize button on the extra monitor by scaling the size of the unity launcher to a little less than default.

Click the gear icon in the top right corner of your window, and choose 'System Settings'

Click on the 'Screen Display' Icon.

Look for a slider bar that says "Scale for menu and title bars:" slide it to the left a bit. Mine is on 0.75

Comment: I'd suggest expanding this answer with an explanation of how to do that.

Comment: hey! this works even in Ubuntu 16.04, and even if I just move the scale to the left, and put it back to the right, they appeared magically, good workaround!

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to have a panel on the second screen, with indicators, menus, and all that. If you don't then you've encountered a bug. Please report it on http://launchpad.net. The number of users with multiple monitors is far lower than those with only one, so these types of bugs are specially important to report.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/876391

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both screens have to be aligned on top.

If both screens are aligned on top at startup, there will be a panel on both screens.

If not, as in my case, there won't be a panel.

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu, the way this site works is you just update your original question with more detail instead of posting an answer.